# Structure inside a structure, nesting of structures

Tags: c, structure

I have

```
   struct node
   {
        int value;
       struct node next;
   };
```

If i do this i get an error `field next has incomplete type`

but when i declare a structure like this it works fine,

```
     struct node
     {
         int value;
         struct node *next;
     };
```

Why is that error? the compiler can get to know tht struct node has already been declared.

Comment: You cannot put a `struct` instance in itself. At best, you can put a pointer to this `struct`.

Comment: What's the complete content of a box that contains itself?

Comment: aren't they identical??

Comment: `Why is that error?` Cannot be determined the structure.

Comment: The data structure would have infinite size. Stack overflow likely :)

Comment: Not sure why this is getting voted down.  The question is simplistic, but I think it meets with all the SO question requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure anyone actually answered your question proper.

You cannot use the structure itself for a couple reasons.  The first is that you've now made the structure self-referential, and there would be no way to actually allocate sufficient space for it.  Every time you tried to allocate it, it contains one of itself, which in turn contains one of itself, which in turn contains one of itself... forever.  So it would take infinite memory.  Second, the compiler doesn't yet know what it even means to be of that type of struct, since it's not complete yet.

However, the compiler does know exactly how much space a pointer to that structure will take -- it's the same as the pointer to any other type.

Also, since memory for the structure itself isn't allocated - just a pointer - there is no infinite recursion.

And since no dereferences are made by adding a pointer, you don't have to have the full definition of the struct yet in order to know what memory offset to go to to access a member of the structure.  That has to wait until the structure is fully defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this

```
struct node
{
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};
```

Regards,
Luka

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node
{
   int value;
   struct node *next;
};
```

This code is OK. You only can put a pointer to the structure

Answer (score 0):

You can add a typedef for don't use struct keyword, and you need a pointer.

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
   int value;
   node *next;
};
```